# Two buttons inside one form, how to tie only one button to submit?

Tags: reactjs, forms, button

in React app, I have a situation, where I need to tie only one button out of two to form submission task. Right now, both buttons submit my data.
Here is some code:

```
<div>
      <h2>create a new anecdote</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          content 
          <input {...content} />
        </div>
        <div>
          author
          <input {...author} />
        </div>
        <div>
          url for more info
          <input {...info} />
        </div>
        <button  onClick={()=> {
          props.setNotification(content.value);
          setTimeout(() => {
            props.setNotification('')
          }, 5000)
          }}>
            create
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </form>
      
    </div>
```

I have tried to put the "Reset" button outside of form. But then, my buttons would sit on the same line, being one on top of the other. I need the Reset button to be inside the form, so they naturally sit next to each other.

More code:

```
const CreateNew = (props) => {
  const content = useField('content')
  const author = useField('author')
  const info = useField('info')

  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if (content.value === '' || author.value === '' || info.value === '') {
      return 
    }
    e.preventDefault()
    props.addNew({
      content: content.value,
      author: author.value,
      info: info.value,
      votes: 0
    })
    navigate('/')
  }
  const handleReset = (e) => {
    
    if (content.value === '' || author.value === '' || info.value === '') {
      return 
    }
    
    e.preventDefault()
    props.addNew({
      content: content.onReset(''),
      author: author.onReset(''),
      info: info.onReset(''),
      votes: 0
    })
  }
```

With the above code, I have created a bug, where I can clear inputs boxes, but then happens I accidently submit an empty data with the same one click on Rest.

Answer (score 0):

give type="submit" to the button you want to tie to form submission.[have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1AZ.png)

Comment: does not work, I give one button type="button", the other type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

Set button type explicitely: `<button type="button" onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>`
This works because it overrides the default button type which is "submit".

Comment: Does not work. still give me an empty data.

Comment: It works here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1hrv9n) , but to be honest, it works just with e.preventDeafult() inside handleReset() as well, so if it's not working to you there must be something else going on...

Comment: You are right, it works without taking into account clearing input boxes with reset clicking. If adding empty input bxes, then submit is unprevented.

Comment: It could be a lot of things then, without knowing what you are doing in `useField`, or what is `props.addNew` , it' can't be debugged further.